# how to create the color swatches in magento and how to show in product detail page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using **Magento 1.7.0.2** . I want to show the **color swatches** in product detail page. I have tried lot of options but i didn't get solution. So any one guide me, how can i create color swatches and how to show product detail page. I have given the example link for what i need exactly. (Eg: http://swatchesproductview.mangoextensions.com/colorswatches/configurable-product-color-and-size.html )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about customizing Magento, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this extension, it might be useful:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-9787.html

Also check:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-custom-option-plus-with-option-swatches.html

Answer (score 2):

Color swatches are not supported in vanilla Magento. You will have to either buy an extension or write your own.

If you want to write your own you should extend select attribute type to show images in case you set a certain flag (that you will have to add to admin). You should also take a look in class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable` (you will probbably have to extend getConfigurableAttributes and getConfigurableAttributesAsArray functions to contain your image data for each attribute value) and `js/varien/configurable.js` file that contains javascript that handles loading of attribute drop-down list content on product pages (this is the code that you will have to extend to show images instead of dropdowns).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Advanced Product Options extension. It provides the functionality for the color swatch.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html